# Parsing a query to php and returning result ERROR T_WHILE

Tags: php, android, sql, database

I am trying to send a query from my app to my php code throgh POST

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);

$query=$_POST['query'];

$result = mysql_query({$query})

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;
}  

print(json_encode($output));
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR ON LINE 15 UNEXPECTED T_WHILE
```

Comment: You missed a `;` at the end of the `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a semi-colon here:

```
$result = mysql_query({$query});
```

Comment: thank you man! i didnt notice :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a semicolon on the line just before --

```
$result = mysql_query({$query})
```

should  be --

```
$result = mysql_query({$query});
```

Usually when you get an error that contains the word "UNEXPECTED" it means the actual problem is just before the place the error is being reported because the parser is getting a character or command while in the wrong state.

Comment: With a piece of debugging lesson )